# Not being able to access the value of a List

Tags: java, list

**Problem**:
This is the result set of my query, which is stored as a `List<String>`.

`1 A ZZZ`

`2 BB YY`

`3 CCC X`

I know about `get(0)` and `get(1)` and so on. But, I am wondering how could I access the 3rd value of each row. Say for example, from the list above I need to access `YY`, how would I go about doing it?

**EDIT**: The question was badly presented. Here is a detailed version:

I am running a SQL query - `select id, company, department from table_matrix` and I get the above mentioned result.

In java, I have written the following code to store the result of the query:

```
List<String> = the above sql query
```

Now I need to access the value of `CCC`, and only `CCC`. In the above table, I need the value of `row 3`, `column 2`. How can I do it if I am using `List<String>`? If that is not possible, how else may I proceed?

Thanks for the previous comments, and future as well.

Comment: You can cast the contents into a String and then use the `substring() `method....

Comment: Can you show a piece of code illustrating what you have tried? Then we can help you by showing where you go wrong.

Comment: We don't even know the content of your list. Why type is it ?

Comment: I'm not stating that this question is particularly bad, but I'm confused as to what it is you're getting at.  Are those entries specifically entities in your `List<String>`?

Comment: How is `YY` the third value?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: @VitaBourn I assume you used JDBC to execute your SQL query. If that's true I'm very sure, your result is not just a list of strings, but a `ResourceSet`, isn't it?

Comment: @isnot2bad You meant `ResultSet` :)

Comment: @meskobalazs Right! Thanks! (Too much EMF coding... ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is a `List<String>`. In this case you can do this for the row:

```
String[] strArray = list.get(1).split(" ");
String third = strArray[2];
```

Of course there are faster ways, but this gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Result set has get method you can use it getInt, getString and it work on the index but it is 1 based index